# Weblogic: The Message Driven Beans in the war file are not reflecting in Weblogic 14.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, ear

I have a Java Web Application that contain EJB as follows,

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "/GE_OM/MQListenerXXXQueue_Channel", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "topicMessagesDistributionMode", propertyValue = "One-Copy-Per-Application"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE")})
```

There is no ejb-jar.xml file as this is annotated with @MessageDriven. However, when I build the war using Maven, get the .war file and deploy in Weblgoic 14.1.1 server, I do not see the EJBs. However, there is a similar project which reflects the EJBs under it. Need help as to know why the EJBs are not reflected.